# Why does 'unauthorized' appear in the startup of kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, unauthorized

I start k8s on my local machine and find most pods are not ready:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-65dbdb44db-zrfpm                     0/1     Running            0          3m9s
kube-system   dashboard-metrics-scraper-545bbb8767-nfnbg   1/1     Running            1          16m
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-nm7kr                  0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5          16m
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-65665f84db-rqxpv        0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   4          118s
kube-system   metrics-server-869ffc99cd-6fhfl              0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5          16m
```

Then I check the status of flannel:

```
kubectl logs  kube-flannel-ds-amd64-nm7kr -n kube-system
```

The log tells me that something is unauthorized:

```
I0809 10:23:51.307347       1 main.go:518] Determining IP address of default interface
I0809 10:23:51.308840       1 main.go:531] Using interface with name wlo1 and address 192.168.1.102
I0809 10:23:51.308894       1 main.go:548] Defaulting external address to interface address (192.168.1.102)
W0809 10:23:51.308917       1 client_config.go:517] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
E0809 10:23:51.620449       1 main.go:243] Failed to create SubnetManager: error retrieving pod spec for 'kube-system/kube-flannel-ds-amd64-nm7kr': Unauthorized
```

Then I check the coredns:

```
E0809 10:28:06.807582       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Unauthorized
```

Then I check the metrics-server:

```
2020/08/09 10:28:06 Starting overwatch
2020/08/09 10:28:06 Using namespace: kube-system
2020/08/09 10:28:06 Using in-cluster config to connect to apiserver
2020/08/09 10:28:06 Using secret token for csrf signing
2020/08/09 10:28:06 Initializing csrf token from kubernetes-dashboard-csrf secret
panic: Unauthorized

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf.(*csrfTokenManager).init(0xc00036f0e0)
        /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf/manager.go:41 +0x446
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf.NewCsrfTokenManager(...)
        /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/csrf/manager.go:66
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.(*clientManager).initCSRFKey(0xc000114080)
        /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:501 +0xc6
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.(*clientManager).init(0xc000114080)
        /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:469 +0x47
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.NewClientManager(...)
        /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:550
main.main()
        /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/dashboard.go:105 +0x20d
```

I use kubernetes 1.18.2.
So what's wrong with that?

Comment: it means the key that issued your ServiceAccount was rotated, thus invalidating those ServiceAccounts; deleting those SAs should, in theory, have k8s recreate them, but you'll have to delete every Pod that uses them, after the new SAs show back up

Comment: Hello @sai does above answer from mdaniel solved your issue? If not could you provide more informations about your infrastructure, how did you install your cluster,  is that kubeadm, have you followed any tutorial?